# How do you switch a negative to a positive and a postive to a negative in a list?

Tags: python, list, function

How do you switch a negative to a positive and a postive to a negative in a list?

I want to make a function to do this. For example `[1,-3, 5]` would become `[-1, 3, -5]`

Comment: Multiply each element in the list by -1.

Comment: Can also use numpy and do `np.array(values) * -1` or `-np.array(values)`

Answer (score 2):

Just use list comprehension:

```
a = [1, -3, 5]
negative = [-x for x in a]
print(negative)
```

Output:

```
[-1, 3, -5]
```